# Copying data from redshift directly to EMR cluster -- Is it a good practice?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

Amazon gives a very detailed documentation for copying data from EMR to Redshift (through S3), but there doesn't seem like any docs on the other way around, which makes me wonder if it's a good practice at all to load data from redshift to EMR (directly, or through some medium)

Theoretically I don't see why not, but I don't know the consequence of it

Comment: well thats fine if you have a good use case for it

Comment: so it's usually recommended against?

Comment: nope. do it if you need to! There may be a better approach but you will need to share the details of your challenge to get help!

Comment: Why not to use [AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/what-is-glue.html)? It uses EMR under the hood but you don't need to care about infrastructure. Moreover, it has great integration with other AWS services (Redshift, s3 etc)

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk hmmm I'll have to look into this. Didn't know it exists.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Redshift Unload.
Export data as Parquet, then read data from EMR Hadoop(Spark, Hive)

```
UNLOAD ('select-statement')
TO 's3://object-path/name-prefix'
authorization
FORMAT PARQUET
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html